# how to check the sequence of the data in an array read from a file data in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, text-parsing

I have a file with usfm data [USFM_file_link](https://github.com/sonyzach/usfm-validator/blob/InlineMarkers/Tests/3JN.usfm) and out of it, I made this array like this with only the markers from each line

```
['id','c','p','v','p','v','v','v','p','v','v','v','v','p','v','v','v','v','p','v','v','v','c','p','v','p','v','v','v' ]
```

I want to check the sequence of markers in each line from this file. so the condition for sequence is

> Each chapter must have at least one \p marker before the first \v marker.

That means for every first **'v'** element after a **'c'** element there require a **'p'** element unless the file is not in the right form. In my understanding i think this is text  parsing but don't know how to check the sequence for this problem. Any help would be appreciated. I am not requesting to help me in coding but a logic of how to check sequence in JavaScript while reading and parsing from a file like this.

Comment: Concatenate the string and use regex? Also, may you add a [mcve] of your efforts so far?

Comment: @evolutionxbox if you see given USFM file as in above link that belongs from the repository. all code is there

Comment: Please put all relevant information in the question itself. Links rot, which makes questions useless for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = ['id', 'c', 'p', 'v', 'p', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'p', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'p', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'p', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'c', 'p', 'v', 'p', 'v', 'v', 'v'];

if (isPatternFound(list, "c", "v", "p")) {
    console.log("Found")
} else {
    console.log("Not found")
}

function isPatternFound(inputList, startValue, followedValue, followedByValue) {
    var cIdx = inputList.indexOf(startValue), isFound=false;
    while (cIdx > -1) {
        inputList.splice(0, inputList.indexOf(startValue));
        inputList.splice(0, inputList.indexOf(followedValue));
        if (inputList[1] == followedByValue) {
            isFound= true;
            return isFound;
        } else {
            isFound= false;
        }
        cIdx = inputList.indexOf(startValue);
    }
    return isFound;
};
```

Comment: @zachi, please mark this as correct if it worked for u